# Sandboxed Application: Retrieve a folders size in MB/GB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox

I would like to find the size of a given path in MB/GB. I have tried before with NSFileManager but every result would turn out zero because of the app sandboxing (frustrating). Is there a method which works? I want to find the size of a hidden folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What difference does it make whether a folder is sandboxed or not?  Whether you use Xcode or Windows Visual Studio, you will get a 0 size if you try to calculate the data size of a folder.  Perhaps, you should run a search with [objective-c] folder size.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a path where you don't have access to by default, like user's home folder? Then you need to request access to it from the user by showing her standard open dialog (NSPanel). If you want to retain this access between launches, you need to generate and store security-scoped bookmark to that location.

Comment: I want to monitor the /.Trash folder

Comment: You need to get access to it first, because it's outside of sandbox.